# How to "update" a column using pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Imagine I have the following table available to me:

```
A: { x: int, y: int, z: int, ...99 other columns... }
```

I now want to transform this, such that `z` is set to `NULL` where `x > y`, with the resulting dataset to be stored as `B`.

and I want to do it without having to explicitly mention all the other columns, as this becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: If you come up with an answer, please update this question with an answer. Whenever I have to do something like this right now, I copy/paste the LOAD line into a FOREACH. I wish I knew of a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is tracked in this JIRA:
[PIG-1693](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1693) There needs to be a way in foreach to indicate "and all the rest of the fields"

Currently I don't know anything simpler than doing what you say or not loading Z and adding a new column Z with the [star expression](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.0/piglatin_ref2.html#sexp).

Comment: Sorry I missed this answer for so long!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to drop some of the column bloat by nesting them in single-row bags and flattening afterwards.

Still, it feels like a bit of a hack. So I'm also investigating cascading to see if it's a better fit for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A feature to facilitate your scenario was added in Pig 0.9. The new project-range operator (..) allows you to express a range of fields by indicating the starting and/or ending field names as in this example:

result = FOREACH someInput GENERATE field1, field2, null as field3, field4 .. ;

In the example above field1/2/3/4 are actual field names. One of the fields is set to null while the other fields are kept intact.

More details in this "New Apache Pig 0.9 Features – Part 3" article: http://hortonworks.com/blog/new-apache-pig-0-9-features-part-3-additional-features/

To solve your specific problem you probably want to do a FILTER and an UNION to combine the results.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can select columns by column number, but that can easily become a nightmare if you change anything at all. I have found column names to be much more stable, and therefore I recommend the following solution:

#### Update mycol when it is between two known columns

You can use `..` to indicate leading, or trailing columns (or inbetween columns). Here is how that would work out if you want to change the value of 'MyCol' to 'updatedvalue'.

```
aliasAfter = FOREACH aliasBefore GENERATE 
             .. colBeforeMyCol, updatedvalue, colAfterMyCol ..;
```