# PigStorage and Variable Schemas from Input

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a comma separated text file like

```
1,abc,1,
2,def,1,2,3,4
3,ghi,1,2
4,jkl,1,5,6,7,8,9
5,mno
```

The text file will always have the first two values, but will have 0 or more values after the second comma.

How can I load this data and give an alias to the first two values?

I can load it and not give an alias to the first two values via:

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```

From here, I can do a `B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS foo:chararray, $1 AS bar:chararray;` but it would discard the rest. It would be nice to do a wildcard and put the rest in a tuple.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
B = foreach A generate $0 as foo:chararray, $1 as bar:chararray, $2..;
```

reference

[Drop single column in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835943/drop-single-column-in-pig)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you need.

Try this one

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (foo:chararray, bar:chararray);
```

This will ignore the other values after the second comma in your file.

Comment: The OP wants to columns after the second comma.  This answer is the exact opposite of what the question was asking

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a Map for reamining fields.